# Change image when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I have a menu with images. Let's say these are the images. When I hover over, it changes to the second image. I want the second image to remain when I click on it (when is active).

```
<a href='index.html'>
   <span>
     <img src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://s3.firstpost.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/1Christmas_GettyImages.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg'"/>
   </span>
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nDkRG

Comment: Welcome to SO, please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to get people to help you.

Comment: why are people downvoting? - I know the explaination isnt clear, but I'm guessing English isnt the guy's first language.

Answer (score 1):

In plain JavaScript (having given the image an `id`, to easily target it):

```
/* called by clicking the link (because the image is a child-element),
   a simple means of preventing the default action: */
function nothing (e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

// the 'event' itself is passed as the first argument to the function
function update (e){
    // find what the event-type is ('click','mouseover', 'mouseout'):
    switch (e.type){
        // if it was the mouseover event, we:
        case 'mouseover':
            /* update the src property, retrieving the new src from the
               custom data-over attribute of the element:
            */
            this.src = this.getAttribute('data-over');
            // break out of the switch:
            break;
        case 'mouseout':
            // if the image doesn't contain the 'clicked' class-name, we:
            if (!this.classList.contains('clicked')){
                /* change the src to the string stored within the custom
                   data-out attribute:
                */
                this.src = this.getAttribute('data-out');
            }
            // break out of the switch:
            break;
        // if it's the 'click' event:
        case 'click':
            /* we add the 'clicked' class if it's not already there,
               and remove it if it is already there:
            */
            this.classList.toggle('clicked')
            break;
    }
}

/* retrieving the relevant image element (by its id, using querySelector
   and CSS-notation:
*/
var image = document.querySelector('#demo'),
// retrieving all the 'a' elements, then selecting only the first:
    link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

// binding an event-handler to the image for the various events:
image.addEventListener('click', update);
image.addEventListener('mouseover', update);
image.addEventListener('mouseout', update);

// binding an event-handler to the 'a' element, to handle the 'click' event:
link.addEventListener('click', nothing);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nDkRG/2/).

Comment: +1 You are the only one here who actually posted a pure javascript solution.  No idea why everyone else decided to use jQuery.  The question is not tagged jQuery, it is tagged javascript, and the OP made no mention of jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

try to add this

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('img').removeAttr('onmouseover').removeAttr('onmouseout');
})
```

updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDkRG/1/)

Comment: who downvoted it? it does exactly what does the question ask... at least bother with some comment...